# Running tests for different functionality simultaneously on sauce labs with java

Tags: java, webdriver, saucelabs

I know I can run the same set of tests simultaneously on different OS/browsers with sauce labs.  Is there a way I can run different sets of test simultaneously with java on sauce labs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem lies not with Saucelabs but with your test library.

Some test libraries such as TestNG (java), allow you to run tests in parallel, and when combined with a data provider to drive the os/browser combination, you should be able to achieve what you want.

Saucelabs itself would only be aware that multiple sessions are being run simultaneously from the same account, it has no awareness of what the sessions are doing.

obviously, your Saucelabs account must support multiple sessions for this to work.